# What exactly is Next.js running on the server during a client-side render?

Tags: next.js, apollo-client

I'm visiting a page that's rendered on the client side and uses Apollo Client to retrieve data from an API server, from the client's web browser.

```
  const { data, error, loading } = useQuery(...);

  console.log('data', data);
```

When I visit this page, the client and the web server **both** console.log non-null data.

Why is the console.log call populated with data, even on the server? Presumably web server isn't calling the API server (in fact, I'm pretty sure it's not even authorized). Is the browser sending its console logs back to the server or something?

This is Next v12.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, Next.js prerendering will run the useQuery hook on the server, however useQuery will return a stub with no data.

In the case above, a third party extension (next-with-apollo) was calling the function `getDataFromTree`, which traverses the entire tree, running all queries on the server side as well as the client.

See also: [apollo-client in next.js with `next-with-apollo` VS the approach shown in next.js docs FAQ (no use of `getDataFromTree`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68848346/apollo-client-in-next-js-with-next-with-apollo-vs-the-approach-shown-in-next-j?rq=2)

Answer (score 0):

to prevent preloading data with Apollo on the server use this approach

https://www.apollographql.com/blog/apollo-client/next-js/next-js-getting-started/#using-apollo-client-for-client-side-data

It's just running request because of how SSR/SSG is currently implemented in Next and other frameworks like Gatsby too.